# Lifetime expectation in renewal process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be interarrival times like the time between two buses coming to a bus station. Let $Y(t)$ be the time until the next renewal, like the time until the next bus from a given time $t$. This is known as excess. Let $U(t)$ be the time since the last renewal, like the time since the last bus. This is known as the age.

Define the lifetime to be $X(t) = Y(t) + U(t)$. Also known as spread.

Find the value of $E(X(t))$ by conditioning.

---

How can I do this? I think you need to condition on the first renewal time. I think the answer is $E(X^2)/E(X)$ but I want to understand how to get it with conditioning expectation.

I know $E(Y(t)) = E(X^2)/2E(X)$ if it helps.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps something like $$\mathbb E[X(t)] = \mathbb E[X(t)\mid X_1 \leqslant t]\mathbb P(X_1 \leqslant t) + \mathbb E[X(t)\mid X_1 > t]\mathbb P(X_1 > t)\ ?$$

Comment: We have $\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbb E[Y(t)] =\frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{2 \mathbb E[X]}$ as well as $\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbb E[X(t)] =\frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{\mathbb E[X]}$, but these are only the limiting results.